# I am attempting to create a binary search program for a school project, but certain numbers cause infinite recursion

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, sorting, binary-search

This is my code:

```
list = []
line = 50

def genList(list):
    i = 0
    while i < 1000:
        list.append(i)
        i += 1
    return list

def displayList(list, line):
    i = 0
    while i < 1000:
        if i != 0 and i % line == 0:
            print('\n')
        print('{0:03}'.format(list[i]), end = ' ')
        i += 1
    print('\n')

def binarySearch(min, max, list, goal):
    mid = min + (max - 1) // 2
    if list[mid] == goal:
        return mid
    elif list[mid] > goal:
        return binarySearch(min, mid - 1, list, goal)
    else:
        return binarySearch(mid + 1, max, list, goal)

genList(list)
displayList(list, line)
goal = int(input('What number do you want to find, from 0 to 999?\n'))

result = binarySearch(0, len(list) - 1, list, goal)
print(result)
```

...and like I said, certain numbers work but others don't, for example 999 will return 999 but 998 will return:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Anyone know what's wrong with it? I'm at a bit of a loss...

Comment: Do you know if the number is in the list?

Comment: `mid = min + (max - 1) // 2`? do you mean  `mid = min + (max - min) // 2` instead as the way to find the middle value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is definitely wrong:

```
mid = min + (max - 1) // 2
```

Perhaps you meant ( as @Nikolaos Chatzis pointed out)

```
mid = min + (max - min) // 2
```

but following works as well and needs one less operation:

```
mid = (min + max) // 2
```

Additionally you should abort recursion if `minval > maxval` (if the value you search for is not in the list)

I didn't look if you can do better. but this should work

```
def binarySearch(minval, maxval, list_, goal):
    mid = (minval + maxval) // 2
    # print(minval, maxval, mid, goal)  # uncomment for debugging
    if minval > maxval:  # couldn't find search value
        return None
    if list_[mid] == goal:
        return mid
    elif list_[mid] > goal:
        return binarySearch(minval, mid - 1, list_, goal)
    else:
        return binarySearch(mid + 1, maxval, list_, goal)
```

Also don't hesitate to add print statements (or logs) for debugging.

It makes it very often obvious what is going wrong.

What you could also do is run some simple test code to show that it works for all cases:

```
for v in range(1000):
    assert binarySearch(0, len(list_) -1, list_, v) == v
```

Also as general recommendation to not stumble into funny or strange bugs.

`min`, `max` and `list` are all python keywords.
You can avoid funny surprises by not using variables with these names. It makes your code also look better with many basic syntax highlighters.

Using them as variable names is not forbidden, but I think it's not a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

`mid = min + (max - 1) // 2` probably should be `(min + max) // 2`. Also, your code should have a base case that returns a value, say `-1` if the element does not exist within the list. Something like `if min > max: return -1` right at the beginning of your search function.